# Unity3D .SetActive() not working with OnTriggerEnter()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game with a 2 part tutorial. The player will shoot a cube to make the 1st part disappear and make the 2nd part appear in it's place. When I play the scene, the Start() void does what I want (makes the 2nd part inactive before the first frame) but then when I shoot the cube with the script the active states are not modified.

I know my raycast works fine as I have already made a level that works all the way through (being timed shooting a bunch of targets). I have also made sure I have allocated the correct game objects to the correct slots on the cube's script (each tutorial part has its own handler object), and I have made sure no objects are hidden before hitting play - all of this stuff was recommended by other people on here.

Any help would be appreciated! Here is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class OnRaycastHitSwitchTutorial : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject TutorialOne;
    public GameObject TutorialTwo;

    void Start()
    {
        TutorialTwo.SetActive(false);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        TutorialTwo.SetActive(true);
        TutorialOne.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question does not include enough information about the desired result - What is meant by "shoot the cube"? There is mention of raycasts but nothing shown in the code included in the question has anything to do with raycasts. First guess, change `OnTriggerenter(Collider other)` from the unity message method to something custom like `OnRaycastHit()` . Then from the code that raycasts, use `GetComponent<OnRaycastHitSwitchTutorial>()` on hit gameobjects, and if the result is not null, call its `OnRaycastHit`. Or better, use an interface with `OnRaycastHit` so you can have varieties reaction